# Why does my font in the OneNote 2010 beta keep changing back to a non-default?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2007, microsoft-onenote-2010

In OneNote options I've set a particular default font.  Then I selected all text in a particular notebook section and change it to the new font.  However, whenever I insert a new line in that existing body of text, it reverts to a font that isn't my default.  Almost as if the incorrect "style" information is somehow embedded in the existing text, even though the text itself is the correct font.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this reply from a user on the Microsoft TechNet forums:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/onenote/thread/7d54d268-53a1-42bc-b184-9d67d5b06298?prof=required

"I've had this sort of problem too ([OneNote is imagining fonts that aren't actually there](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/onenote/thread/5db92853-b013-473b-90e2-c85776669865)).  I'm pretty sure it will be fixed before the final 2010 release.  [Given The down key doesn't work in OneNote most of the time when using fixed width fonts](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/onenote/thread/962e0def-ecbb-470a-aea5-92a0df7ea1a7), it seems like there are significant font-related problems... and since I was told that the fixed width font issue was already fixed in an unreleased version, hopefully the other issues are fixed too.

A quick fix would be to just use the font OneNote seems to want you to use.  That's what I'm doing (though I really miss my fixed width fonts!!).  Also, I've not had the magic font issue with the 2007 notebook formats."

Answer (score 3):

A temporary solution until Microsoft fixes this bug is just to click "Clear All Formatting" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) and then continue on your work. I found that it makes the font whatever you set it to as the default. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens only in the existing text box (I define 'text box' to be that box which is created whenever you click on an empty area of the page - a box where you can start typing).

While editing/typing in an existing text box, if you would have changed the default font, the above problem is observed.

In order to solve this:

1. Click on the empty space in the same page. A new text box is created.
2. Copy the contents of the old box to this new box. If you hit enter (next line), the changed default font is always applied.